# Linking glut to Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt4, glut

I want to combine OpenGL with glut to Qt.
I'm using Windows. My version of Qt is 4.7.4, 32 bit.

I followed the tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nzHSkY4K18

I also checked some other questions of people but they didn't gave me an answer.

The part before including glut works fine.
But when I try to include glut it doesn't work.
The errors are:

> undefined reference to glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK

and more undefined references to glutfunctions.

I copied the glut-libraries and headers to the appropriate folders in the MinGW folder.
But I wasn't sure if this was the right folder.

Comment: Why do you want to use GLUT and Qt? If you're using Qt, then *use Qt*; both Qt and GLUT do the same thing as far as OpenGL is concerned: they create and manage OpenGL windows. You don't need them *both*.

Comment: I'm working in a group and we made a program in QT and we want to display it with glut

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can't display a program with another program. Unless it's a virtual machine or something, and GLUT very much is not. If you have a Qt application that uses OpenGL, you don't need to make that work with GLUT.

Comment: But the tutorial in de link does it and it works

Answer (score 1):

**MinGW:**

Copy glut.h to **%dir%\MinGW\include\GL**

Copy glut32.lib to **%dir%\MinGW\lib**

Copy glut32.dll to **C:\windows\system32**

Add **%dir%\MinGW\bin** to the system's environmental variables.

**Visual Studio:**

Navigate to

**%dir% \Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\**

Place the **.h** files in   ...\include\GL

Place the **.lib** files in     ...\lib

Restart Visual Studio.